# nodejs - __dirname not replacing with regex?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I've been trying to use regex to replace `__dirname` in logging. However it never seems to work. For instance, in an error stack:
`error.stack.includes(__dirname)` returns true
`error.stack.reaplce(/__dirname/g, ".\\")` returns the stack trace unchanged

Manually writing out the directory name works, using `.replace(__dirname, ".\\")` also works, but obviously doesn't replace everything.
I feel like this might just be me being stupid but, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `/__dirname/g` is literally replacing the string "__dirname" - one solution is to use `replaceAll` in your working attempt, or to construct a regex from the value if __dirname - though, you do have to escape any "special" (regex) characters

Comment: You might need to create the regex differently `new RegExp(__dirname)`?

Comment: You have a typo in `reaplce`. Also, what is `__dirname` value? Please provide a JavaScript snippet to showcase the problem, right now, it is not clear what is going on.